# Java Textfield printing query

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, uitextfield, jtextfield

Hi I would like to loop from number 1 to 10 and print them all under each other in my netbeans TextField.

I tried placing the textfield within the loop, but it over-writes the last value and so it doesn't work. Any idea how I may solve this issue? Thanks

Code:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

 String test = null;
 int i = 0;

    while(i<10){
     test = String.valueOf(i);
     test = test+"/n"
    }

    jTextField3.setText(test); 

  }
```

Comment: Do you want to show 10 textfields? can you show us what have you tried yet?

Comment: no just one text field, yes sure let me upload..

Comment: \n do not work with a textfield since it only display one line of text. This is why you only see the last entry. Use a JTextArea instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose a JTextArea is what you are looking for. Try something like this:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
   textArea.append(i+"\n");
```

A TextField is usually used for input, a "line" where a user can enter something. TextArea is probably what you want. Here you should call the `append()` method, enter the value you want to append and add a newline with `\n`

If it overwrites your last value, make sure that you create the field outside of the loop, and just call the refrence. If you do `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();` inside the loop, a new area will be created each iteration overwriting the one you had

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say without seeing the code; you should post the relevants parts of it when you ask for help.

My guess is that you are doing something like that.

```
myTextField.setValue(Integer.toString(i));
```

`set` always deletes previous value and adds a new one.

In addition to that, a JTextField does not support multiple lines. Try with a JTextArea.